# GRE Math Subject Test Overkill for Statistics MS?

Tags: graduate-admissions, statistics

I got a degree in Applied Mathematics, but while I aced my Statistics courses, my performance in my math courses was weak. I have retaken some of the courses but will not be able to retake them all. Is the Math Subject GRE, though difficult, worth the effort of preparing and doing, hopefully, well on it?

Comment: Why don't you check the admissions page of the program you are applying to? I'm sure they will say something like "GRE math subject test required/recommended/not required/not considered" etc

Comment: Some mention that it is "strongly encouraged", but only in general for a program: they do not specify if it is even important for MS programs. Others don't mention it at all on the MS applicant pages. The main point of my question, is it even worth it to take the test for just MS?

Answer (score 3):

If the Math GRE is "strongly encouraged" and you're concerned that your performance in mathematics courses will negatively affect your application, then yes, you should take it. It doesn't matter so much that it's only for a Master's degree, because the GRE is only useful as a predictor for courses, which is Master's-level work.